# How to hide items in combo-boxes?

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a combobox with various items, item1 item2 item3

They all show as visible and are selectable, but i wanna hide for example item3, i want him to appear only when a variable equals 1

is this possible? Because all of the items i have in the collection including item3 are showing up.

I'm using the following to disable its selection

```
  if (ComboBox1.SelectedItem == "item3")
        {
            ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
  }
```

and it works fine, but i wanna actualy make item3 invisible unless other variable is set as 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wait until the other variable is set and then add that item to the combo box. Something like this.

```
if (variable == 1) {
    ComboxBox1.Items.Add("item3");
}
```

Comment: that's pretty neat, but to use that i would have to be able to access the combo-box in a different form, is that possible?

Comment: Could you give a little more detail on what you are doing? Are you showing a dialog box and then returning to the original form?